# is_page "range" for if statement?

Tags: php, functions, shortcode

I'm trying to shorten my code, but struggling to find an answer, or even how to code it as I'm learning.

As I understand it, is_page doesn't allow a page range... is there an alternate way that I can do this?

My current code is:

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    if (is_page( '310', '312', '314', '316', '318', '320', '322', '324', '326' )) {
        echo do_shortcode('[example shortcode]');
    }
    else {
        echo do_shortcode('[example shortcode]');
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have so many pages I need to do in my "range". It would be nice for example to do, 310 - 326.

Off the top of my head, could I use the range() function to create a page range variable, and then call that variable later?

Can someone help me with some ideas on this one, and possibly describe some things I am doing wrong, as it helps me learn.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Keep in mind that not all IDs in that range will be page posts, there could be nav menu items, attachments, links, posts, etc

Comment: @TomJNowell I'm going purely by the page id #'s, are you saying that's not a good idea? What would be a better way of doing this, thanks so much. :)

Comment: pages are posts, page IDs are post IDs, specifically posts of type `page`. They're not stored separately, and there are other kinds of posts. Be specific about which pages you want, or better yet, if you need to group things, use a taxonomy. Also keep in mind that what you're doing here will only work on a single site, and can never work elsewhere as the IDs change. A tag/category/custom taxonomy would make this portable, and simplify the code, as well as allowing you to dynamically change things via a UI

Comment: @TomJNowell I'm following what you're saying, my site however, only uses "pages"... I have no "posts". I really like your idea of using a tag / category though!! Thank you for that. :)

Comment: Every image you upload and every item in a nav menu is stored as a post, of type `attachment` and `nav_menu_item`. You might not notice them, but they're there. Else WP would have to scan the uploads folder which would be super slow

Comment: @TomJNowell So you're suggesting that if someone viewed an attachment with the same post id, given the code above, the shortcode would run?

Comment: It might, I couldn't comment further though without knowing more about the shortcode. Also keep in mind drafts and revisions may be in there. A taxonomy based approach would be ideal

Answer (score 2):

I think you should create range as variable and set it to `is_page()` something like this should work.

```
$range = range(310, 326);
if(is_page($range)){
    // your code..
}
```

`is_page()` function can accept array as argument. And [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function return array. This example works fine for me.